# Android Text To Speech Not Working

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I am Trying to Run a tts on a static String , But I'm not able to hear any output from TTS, Here's my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
CircleMenu.OnItemClickListener,GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MaterialDialog.Builder materialDialog;
    CardAdapter cardAdapter;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    private static int RC_SIGNIN=0;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    FirebaseClient firebaseClient;
    TextToSpeech textToSpeech;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textToSpeech=new TextToSpeech(this,this);
        textToSpeech.speak("I am Supposed TO Shout",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null,null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        textToSpeech.stop();
        textToSpeech.shutdown();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status)
    {
        if(status==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your Device Is Not Missing TTS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            int language=textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            if(language==TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || language==TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED)
            {

            }
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "Your Device Is Missing TTS", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know where I am Wrong, I looked for similar codes on github, they are exactly same as me like here [Credits:SurvingWithAndroid](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2015/02/android-text-to-speech-tts.html)
But They Seem To Be working in my device

Comment: You are calling `speak()` before the TTS engine has been fully initialized i.e. before the `onInit()` callback has run.

Comment: actually I want to call speak() on ActivityResult. What Should I Do?

Comment: Then call `speak()` in `onActivityResult()` instead. Otherwise the code seems fine, so probably at that point the TTS engine is already fully up and running.